# How does long value fit in float data type in Java without loss of precision

Tags: java, floating-point, precision, long-integer

How does long value fit in float data type in Java without loss of precision. Because if there is loss of precision then the following snippet should have produced

```
long lMax = Long.MAX_VALUE;
float f = lMax;
System.out.println(lMax == f);

Output 
true
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is, that for comparison of `long` and `float` the `long` value is being cast to `float`, and the same loss of precision occurred as in the assignment...

If you want to "detect" loss of precision, try using `BigDecimal`s, something like this:

```
System.out.println(new BigDecimal(lMax).compareTo(new Bigdecimal(f)));
```

I know that the constructor `BigDecimal(double)` will get the `float` cast to `double` but there is no precision lost...

### Edit

For most people `long` seems to have more "precision" than `float`. However `float` has a range of `+/-10^38`, which is much larger than `long`'s...

### Tests

```
long lMax = Long.MAX_VALUE;
float f = lMax;
System.out.println( lMax == f );
System.out.println( new BigDecimal( lMax ).compareTo( new BigDecimal( f ) ) );
System.out.println( ( (Float) f ).longValue() == lMax );
System.out.println( ( (Long) lMax ).floatValue() == f );
System.out.printf( "%d, %d%n", ( (Float) f ).longValue(), lMax );

f = --lMax;
System.out.println( lMax == f );
System.out.println( new BigDecimal( lMax ).compareTo( new BigDecimal( f ) ) );
System.out.println( ( (Float) f ).longValue() == lMax );
System.out.println( ( (Long) lMax ).floatValue() == f );
System.out.printf( "%d, %d%n", ( (Float) f ).longValue(), lMax );
```

Outputs:

```
true
-1
true
true
9223372036854775807, 9223372036854775807
true
-1
false
true
9223372036854775807, 9223372036854775806
```

Comment: It's other way. float value is being cast to long. float f2 = 9223372036854775807.5f;
System.out.println(lMax == f2); Even this will return true. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

The [Binary Numeric Promotion](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se6/html/conversions.html#170983) rules in the Java language Specification are key to understanding the behavior of the code snippet in the question. In particular "Otherwise, if either operand is of type float, the other is converted to float."

In the `lMax == f` comparison, lMax is converted to float exactly as was done by the `float f = lMax` assignment. If you take the same input value, do the same transformation on it twice, and compare the results they will be equal regardless of whether the transformation changed the value or not.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a good demonstration of the precision loss, try this little script when getting system time in milliseconds and converting from long to float:

```
class Scratch {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

        float currentF;
        long currentL;
        float lastNewF = 0;
        long lastL = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long diff;

        while (true) {
            currentL = System.currentTimeMillis();
            currentF = (float) currentL;
            if (currentF != lastNewF) {
                // we finally got a new "different" float value
                lastNewF = currentF;
                diff = currentL - lastL;
                lastL = currentL;
                System.out.println(diff + " milliseconds since we got a new time as float");
            }
            Thread.sleep(250);
        }
    }
}
```

You can see from the output that you are sometimes losing up to 2 minutes of precision:

```
0 milliseconds since we got a new time as float
46964 milliseconds since we got a new time as float
131054 milliseconds since we got a new time as float
131093 milliseconds since we got a new time as float
131077 milliseconds since we got a new time as float
```

Answer (score -1):

The value of lMax =9223372036854775807; // It might be different in your JVM.

Value of f = 9.223372E18

Now when you compare `lMax == f`, first f is converted to long and then comparison happens. After converting into long, f value is same as lMax.

Even same apply for following code.

```
long lMax = Long.MAX_VALUE; // value is 9223372036854775807
float f =lMax;
float f2 = 9223372036854775807.5f;
System.out.println(lMax == f);
System.out.println(lMax == f2);
```

Output

```
true
true
```

Here f2 is losing decimal value when compared to long. And long value of f2 is same as lMax.

Answer (score -1):

lMax is a long number. When u assign it to a float it will lose the precision.

> float f = lMax;

When you compare a long to a float, internally either long is converted to a float or float is converted to a long. your code

> lMax == f

will be similar to

> ((Float)f).longValue() == lMax

which is 9.223372E18 == 9.223372E18   true

or

> ((Long)lMax).floatValue() == f

which is 9223372036854775807 == 9223372036854775807  true

in either way the answer is true.

Comment: If `f` lost precision, converting it back to `long` would result in different `long` value, and lost precision could be seen... (Speaking in general, not about `Long.MAX_VALUE`...)

Comment: No it will give the same result. Check it once.

Comment: I am concerned about this question. In general, what you said was correct.

Comment: `Long.MAX_VALUE -1` gives `false`.... (`System.out.printf( "%d, %d%n", ( (Float) f ).longValue(), lMax );` outputs: `9223372036854775807, 9223372036854775806`)

Comment: Yeah, exactly. But here he is dealing with `Long.MAX_VALUE`. That's why I said that.

Comment: I think that value seemed to be "big enough" to test loss of precision...